# Print google map with directions on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got google map on my webapp - working with the JavaScript API V3.
I give my users the ability to manage some routes, using the google map directions.
Now, my problem is that I want to give them the ability to print it (just the map, not the entire website).

I've tried the following:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open("_blank", "", '');
var contents = document.getElementById("mapMainCanvas");
OpenWindow.document.write(contents.innerHTML);
```

This indeed open a new tab with the map, but without the directions.
Also, I couldn't find any "print" option in the API.
Does anybody solved this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var content = document.getElementByID('mapMainCanvas'); //has to be first.
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(content);
win.print();
win.close();
```

I hope it will work!

(Please let me know if it does or not.)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work, but I think the problem is in a different place in my code. Will update.

Comment: Check if you have used mapCanvas, map_canvas, mapMainCanvas or map_main_canvas. The problem could be in there.

Comment: What do you mean? my div id is mapCanvas. this is problematic?

Comment: If you say your div is mapCanvas, then I know what your problem is: in the JavaScript you refer to `mapMainCanvas` instead of `mapCanvas`! Make the div in your html have the same id as in your JS and I think it'll work!

Comment: This solution worked for me. You must be sure you've got the right ID of the directions div, as Jaapyse pointed out.

Comment: document.getElementById('mapMainCanvas');  correct one.

Comment: I know it is late but when I use this code snippet. it only gives me markers on print and not the map layer. could you please suggest me any alternative for this? It would be helpful for me :)

Comment: With win.document.write(content); just print the string [object HTMLDivElement]. With win.document.write(content.innerHTML); it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a print stylesheet and use a CSS to make it only print out the map, by hiding everything else? You may need to fiddle with classes using jQuery/other if you want users to be able to print that page normally.

Instructions on starting with print stylesheets can be found here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/